# Images size xxhdp

Tags: android, image, image-resizing, rescale

Hi I want to make app with a lot of pictures but if I put all images to all drawable folders my app has a big size, so one of you recommended me to put image to only xxhdp (android will resize it)

There is my problem: I have device with hdp:

```
scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;// scale is 1,5
```

so if I want to have images 75x75 in hdp I will put 150x150 to xxhdp but it works WRONG(resize it to 50x50). I have tried to put it to xhdp and it works good(but shouldn´t) so I don´t know where is problem. I use convert ratio:

```
ldpi | mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
0.75 | 1    | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4
```

Comment: how do you know it's being resized to 50x50 px?

Comment: I have tested it with another picture 50x50, they were same.

Comment: Just clarifying - you put the other picture in the hdpi folder?

Comment: not to HDP but only to drawable with size 50x50 for all devices

Comment: Of course, you only have to put the xxhdpi picture into the `/res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder, AND NOWHERE ELSE.

Comment: `/res/drawable`? this is used by the **mdpi** resolution (same as `/res/drawable-mdpi`)

Comment: @user3934048 if you put the 50x50 in just res/drawable then it would have been scaled up to 75x75 on an hdpi device, and your 150x150 image in xxhdpi folder would be scaled down to 75x75, and they'd look the same size. So, everything is working. If you want to confirm, take a screenshot from a real device (or a 1:1 resolution emulator) and measure the pixels.

Comment: Now I understand thank u all.